# Launching an exe from java

Tags: java, performance, exe

I understand the following is the typical code to launch an exe from java

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc = rt.exec("some.exe");
```

or with parameter

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder("some.exe","param1","param2").start();
```

I have a web application which wraps an exe and users can execute these on request. As I understand the above two approaches will always **create a new process** on **every request**. I want to avoid this.

Is there way, wherein I keep a **pool of reusable loaded instances** and use them in the typical **concurrent scenario**. I want *avoid* a situation wherein each user request launches a new process.

Comment: have you tried if there is any real overhead or if your java runtime pools this already?

Comment: does your EXE support simultaneous runs? how can you avoid process creation if typical EXE expects only one cycle of running, execution and temination???

Comment: This could turn into a threading nightmare

Comment: @eznme, when I execute any of above code, I see multiple instances created in the task Manager. Which I don't want

Comment: @Santosh, notepad does not support what you need. I wasn't even say correct way because it is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on whether `some.exe` supports this. For example, the command `ls` (or `dir`) does its thing and stops. There is no way to tell it "do it again" - you need a way to communicate with the process and the process must have some interface (usually stdio) which you can use to remote control it.

If your external process can't do it, then you must create a new process per request or you must run the process somewhere else and keep the *results* in a cache for some time, so several user requests get the same data without you having to run the process.

So if you get 100 requests per user and minute and it's okay for the data to be one minute old, then you could run the process once per minute and reuse the old results.

Answer (score 1):

It is the starting of the external process that is expensive, not the creation of the Java object `Process`.

If your exe is implementing a server of some kind with a protocol to communicate you would just start it and use that protocol. But then this question would not have arosen.

If it is a simple tool, e.g. something that processes a file, you need to start it each time and rely (or tweak) on the operating system's / file system's cache mechanisms. There is no way to pause or reuse it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [Apache Commons Pool](http://commons.apache.org/pool/)? It should be good enough for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

How about [Commons Pool](http://commons.apache.org/pool/) combined with [Commons Exec](http://commons.apache.org/exec/) ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you transfer the parameters on the command line, and the executed subprocess cannot be recycled, nor stays persistent in memory, your request does not appear very useful - the only thing you can save is the creation of the process frame, but only to a certain degree.